# Issue during SOAP response deserialization of complex referenced types

Tags: c#, serialization, soap, response

I need to deserialize a SOAP message into C# class. Here an example of a SOAP response structure:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.it">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <env:Body>
    <ns0:objA env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <result href="#ID1" />
    </ns0:objA>
    <ns0:ArrayOfObjB id="ID1" env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ans1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ans1:Array" ans1:arrayType="ns0:ObjB[3]">
      <item href="#ID2" />
      <item href="#ID3" />
      <item href="#ID4" />
    </ns0:ArrayOfObjB>
    <ns0:ObjB id="ID2" env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns0:ObjB">
      <ns0:field_1 xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ns0:field_1>
      <ns0:field_2 xsi:type="xsd:string">2016</ns0:field_2>
      <ns0:field_3 xsi:type="xsd:string">a</ns0:field_3>
    </ns0:ObjB>
    <ns0:ObjB id="ID3" env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns0:ObjB">
      <ns0:field_1 xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ns0:field_1>
      <ns0:field_2 xsi:type="xsd:string">2016</ns0:field_2>
      <ns0:field_3 xsi:type="xsd:string">b</ns0:field_3>
    </ns0:ObjB>
    <ns0:ObjB id="ID4" env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns0:ObjB">
      <ns0:field_1 xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ns0:field_1>
      <ns0:field_2 xsi:type="xsd:string">2016</ns0:field_2>
      <ns0:field_3 xsi:type="xsd:string">c</ns0:field_3>
    </ns0:ObjB>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

In Visual Studio 2015, I create the classes hierarchy by paste this XML code as 
classes. I call the deserialization method provided by System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter class using this code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseMessageXML));

SoapFormatter sf = new SoapFormatter();
object o = sf.Deserialize(ms);
```

I catch the following exception:

```
Parse Error, no assembly associated with XML key ns0 objA
```

How can I fix this issue?

I've tried to use self-imported WSDL classes created by importing the Web Service References but I cannot get valorized the associated object. 
Seems C# cannot resolve the "href" attribute references.

Thanks a lot for any kind of help :)